# Unable to update a request using a findOneAndUpdate in Mean Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I want to post a request in using a field called `token`. This is my mongoose schema

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String
  },

  resetPasswordToken: {
    type: String
  },
  resetPasswordExpires: {
    type: Date
  }

});
```

This is my routes file from `user.js`

```
router.put('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
    console.log('listening');
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {resetPasswordToken:req.params.token},
        {
            password: req.body.password,
            resetPasswordToken: undefined,
            resetPasswordExpires: undefined
        },
        function(err,user) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err + 'is here');
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

This is from where I'm sending `POST request.

```
resetPassword(passwordData) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    console.log(passwordData);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/reset/'+passwordData.token,passwordData,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

No action is getting taking place I'm unable to see the `listening` in my cmd. For a user I already have token value as

```
"resetPasswordToken" : "2a287acacf7d5e98de9a158c8be82744ef0302f9"
```

I'm able to update using postman but unable to update with code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to process the requests by postman and not by client there are 2 possibilities:

- CORS: Use the following code, before processing all your requests

  `app.use((req,res,next)=>{
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
      next()
  })`
- Use x-http-method-override header: As put or delete requests sometimes are not allowed. 
  This can be done while sending in the client or in the server before processing the request ( [click here for the node module used](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) )

Comment: yes I'm using `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
  });` But still I'm facing problem I have also tried with our code no change. Please use parenthasis in your code.

Comment: Use method-override header

Comment: `var methodOverride = require('method-override');`
`app.use(methodOverride());` yes, I'm using them......

Comment: after that set override for put

Comment: how do I ? Can you describe?

Comment: app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'))

Comment: no use. And moreover, I have another function where I've used put and delete method and they work fine. In this method, I have also used `post` instead of `put` and no result